# How to add competitor property to a SportsEvent Event Type

Tags: php, wordpress, schema.org, json-ld

I am having problems configuring schema properly with PHP for this specific property - competitor. The issue is that instead of showing two competitors, the markup testing tool only shows one competitor instead. Here is how my code looks like:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Schema.org for Football
* Description: Add SportsEvent Schema.org in JSONld to site
* Plugin URI: 
* Author: Danstan
* Author URI: 
* Version: 1.0.0
* License: GPL2 or later
* License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/


function addschema() //Function for Schema.org
{
global $post;
if (is_singular('h2h')) { //only for post type matches
$schema_sportsevent = array(
    '@context'  => "http://schema.org",
    '@type'     => "SportsEvent",
    'name' => get_the_title($post->ID),
    'description' => get_the_content($post->ID),
    'url' => get_permalink(),
    'startDate' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start_date' ),
    'endDate'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'end_date' ),
    'image'   => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID),

    'competitor' => array(
        '@type' => "SportsTeam",
        'name'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'home_team' ),
        'image'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'logo_left' ),
    ),

    'competitor' => array(
        '@type' => "SportsTeam",
        'name'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'away_team' ),
        'image'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'logo_right' ),
    ),

    'location' => array(
        '@type' => "Place",
        'name'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'venue_name' ),
        'address' => array(
        '@type' => "PostalAddress",
        'postalCode'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zip_postal_code' ),
        'streetAddress'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'street_address' ),
        'addressLocality'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'locality_city' ),
        'addressRegion'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'address_region' ),
        'addressCountry'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'country' ),
    )
    )
);
echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . json_encode($schema_sportsevent) . '</script>'; 
//encode schema for matches
}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addschema'); //Add Schema to header`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an Array of competitor objects (In your code you use two separate objects).

```
"competitor": [
      {
        "@type": "SportsTeam",
        "name": "United States"
      },
      {
        "@type": "SportsTeam",
        "name": "Japan"
      }
    ],
```

Example her:
https://schema.org/competitor

**Testing screenshot** (Missing other properties):
[image]